# I would like my text to appear from left to right and disappear from left to right as well

Tags: javascript, css, animation, text

I made a simple text with a transition, appearing from left to right when I hover it in CSS.

My code is very simple, as seen in the snippet.

So of course, when I remove my mouse cursor, it is animated in the other direction and the text disappears from right to left.
BUT
I'd like it to disappear from left to right and then reset so it can appear again from left to right, and that's where I'm stuck.

What would be your approach to get such an effect?

Thanks!

```css
.text{
    transition: max-width 700ms linear;
    max-width: 0%;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.container:hover .text{
    max-width: 100%;
}

.container{
    padding: 10px 0 10px 0;
    width: fit-content;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="text">THIS IS MY TEXT</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You will have to use css transitions for that

Comment: Could you make a runnable snippet - at the moment the code you have shown sort of can do nothing as there is nothing to hover over. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @AHaworth I added a working snippet.
@ yo_sup Transition is what I'm using.

Answer (score 1):

You could use CSS animations for this - in the non-hovered state the text moves to left: 100% position and in the hovered state it moves from the -100% position to the 0 position.

If you do this with transitions (rather than setting position left) then the container will maintain the width of the child text.

The wrinkle with this approach is that the very first time, ie onload, the text can be seen going from left to right. To get round this this snippet has a little bit of a hack, the container has opacity 0 for the fist 700ms of the page's life and then is seen.

```css
.text {
  display: inline-block;
  width: fit-content;
  animation: out linear 700ms forwards;
  transform: translateX(100%);
}

@keyframes out {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
}

.container:hover .text {
  transform: translateX(0%);
  animation: in linear 700ms;
}

@keyframes in {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(0%);
  }
}

.container {
  padding: 10px 0 10px 0;
  width: fit-content;
  rheight: fit-content;
  animation: reveal 700ms linear;
  overflow: hidden;
}

@keyframes reveal {
  0%,
  99% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="text">THIS IS MY TEXT</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but unfortunately, this is not the same animation as what I'm looking for. In yours, the text is moving from left to right. In mine, the text is appearing from left to right.
I can't even use a mask the color of my background since I've an animated background behind my text.

Comment: Could you include a fuller description and code in your question as the background is pertinent (and may be part of the answer!).

Comment: Please see my answer to myself at the top, I managed to do it using clip-path. Problem almost solved then, mostly thanks to you!

Answer (score 1):

I managed to do it, thanks to A Haworth for pointing me in the right direction.
I now need to retrieve the actual clip-path value so when the mouse is not over before the end of the animation, it doesn't 'jump' like this. I guess I'll need some JS here if this is even possible to do.

```css
.text{
    animation: out linear 700ms forwards;
}

.container:hover .text{
    animation: in linear 700ms;
}

.container{
    padding: 10px 0 10px 0;
    width: fit-content;
    animation: reveal 700ms linear;
}

@keyframes in {
    0% {
        clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, 0% 100%);
    }
    100% {
        clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 100% 0%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
    }
}

@keyframes out {
    0% {
        clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 100% 0%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
    }
    100% {
        clip-path: polygon(100% 0%, 100% 0%, 100% 100%, 100% 100%);
    }
}

@keyframes reveal {
    0%,
    99% {
      opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {
      opacity: 1;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="text">THIS IS MY TEXT</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   <p class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Saepe, praesentium.</p>
  
.text{
        transition: max-width 700ms linear;
        opacity: 0;
        height: 20px;
        overflow: hidden;
        max-width: 0px;
    }
    
    .text:hover{
        opacity: 1;
        max-width: 100%;
    }
```

Comment: How does this make the text disappear from left to right?
This is exactly what I'm doing by the way (minus the opacity which is useless since max-width is at 0px).